# URL truncates the anchor tags when window.open used from Office.js add-in

Tags: office-js

I am trying to create an add-in for Word/PPT which open a new window using `window.open`.

On a Windows machine, the URL truncates the anchor tags. For example, `http://www.example.com/default.htm#tag` changes to `http://www.example.com/default.htm`

This works as expected on Office for Mac as well as outside of the Office add-in.

The code I'm using:

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            app.initialize();
            $('#reprobutton').click(openInNewWindow);
        });
    };

    function openInNewWindow(url) {
        url = "http://www.example.com/default.htm#tag";
        window.open(url, 'windowTab');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Office.js includes a [Dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) specifically for this scenario.

In order to open a new window for a URL outside of your add-in, you will need to first open a page within your add-in and subsequently redirect the user once `Office.initialize` has fired.

For example, to open a dialog to for `http://www.example.com/default.htm#tag` you would use Dialog API to open a local page:

```js
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://myAddinDomain/myDialog.html');
```

In `myDialog.html` you can then redirect them to the URL you want with something like this:

```js
<script>
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        window.location('http://www.example.com/default.htm#tag');
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Marc - this is good info ! 
I had a discussion with the dev team. They were already aware of this and suggested they can’t use dialog API for opening Help Page as user loses control on right-hand pane when dialog opens. It may lead to bad user experience. We need a way to open the Help URL in a separate window without affecting the ongoing processing of the add-in, that’s why we used window.open(). 
Please let me know if there’s any other way to achieve this..

Comment: If it is simply a help link, you should be able to just use `<a href="url" target="_blank">` rather than `window.open`